# Is it possible to use mariabackup to backup a 10.3 db and restore it to a 10.6 db?

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-10.3

I have successfully backed up a **10.3** mariadb database from PC A (ubuntu 20.04).

On PC B (Ubuntu 22.04), i tried to restore it to a brand new freshly installed **10.6** mariadb.

When preparing the restoration ( `mariabackup --prepare --target-dir=/my_nfs_share/` ), i receive the following error :

```
[ERROR] InnoDB: Upgrade after a crash is not supported. The redo log was created with Backup 
10.3.38-MariaDB. You must start up and shut down MariaDB 10.4 or earlier on the data directory.
```

Onto another brand new pc (Ubuntu 20.04 , same 10.3 Mariadb Version, freshly installed), everything is running smoothly.

I concluded  that when restoring a mariadb database with **mariabackup**, I must have the exact same mariadb database version on both the source and target servers.

Can someone guide me on this ?
Should i use mariadb-dump instead ?

Regards,
Pierre

Comment: Not that way, but there is a process documented in the mariaDB site https://mariadb.com/kb/en/upgrading-between-major-mariadb-versions/

Answer (score 0):

The prepare step must be applied from the same MariaDB (major.minor) version that took the backup.

Perform the same step using MariaDB-10.3:

```
mariabackup --prepare --target-dir=/my_nfs_share/
```

After that it will be possible to restore that to any later version.

Run [mariadb-upgrade](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-upgrade/) on the later version after it starts up.